# Is there a way to Bulk Insert into a SQL Server table based on a column value

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I have a comma-delimited file. Either the first column starts with H or D.

For instance:

```
H, 1, 2, 3, 4
D, 9, 10, 11, 12
```

I want to be able to insert all the `H` records into table `HTemp` and `D` records into another table `DTemp`.

How do I go about doing this?

I currently have no idea on how to approach this. For example to add to `HTemp` based on the first cell value = H, however I do not know how to tell it IF cell value equals H:

```
BULK INSERT HTemp
FROM 'C:\CSVData\Temp.csv'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    TABLOCK
)
```

I cannot figure out how ot tell it to use the first cell value to determine which table to insert into.

Comment: Insert into a single table (a new one) and then do the work to split to each table afterwards using two insert statements.

Comment: I am using SQL Server.

Comment: I agree with @JNevill, dump everytyhing into one table (a staging table) first, then sort it out later into two tables.

Comment: `CSV` means something very specific. In a CSV file there aren't multiple `H` records per row, there's a single row that starts with `H`. `BULK INSERT` is very specific too, it's the process of *quickly* importing data from a file into a table with no transformations. What you describe is completely different

Comment: If all rows contain the same number of fields you may be able to insert them into a staging table and transpose them with SQL. An easier option would be to write your own code eg in C# or any other language you prefer to read individual values and insert them to the tables you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use findstr on Windows to separate the D and records into two separate files and then use bcp to copy the data into separate respective tables.